# Convert <List<List<object>> to <List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, string, list, object, windows-phone-8.1

I do app for windows phone 8.1 and now I need to convert List(List(object)) to List(List(string))...

```
    public List<List<string>> ExecuteScalarEx()
    {
        if (_conn.Trace)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Executing Query: " + this);
        }

        List<List<object>> result = new List<List<object>>();
        List<List<string>> stringList = new List<List<string>>();

        var stmt = Prepare();

        while (SQLite3.Step(stmt) == SQLite3.Result.Row)
        {
            int columnCount = SQLite3.ColumnCount(stmt);

            List<object> row = new List<object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
                var colType = SQLite3.ColumnType(stmt, i);
                object val = ReadColEx(stmt, i, colType);
                row.Add(val);
            }
            result.Add(row);
        }

        //*** I NEED CONVERT HERE! ****
        //stringList = ....;


        return stringList;
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? It could be as simple as using 2 nested loops..

Comment: What have you tried? can you guarrantee they are all castable? if so why do you have a `object` list to begin with?

Comment: I try to cast and this: stringList = new List<List<string>>(result);

Comment: I updated psot and show my all code!

Comment: Not really, it looks like `ReadColEx` must return a string so why not just cast that and store them in a `List<String>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with normal Linq, but Tim's solution is neater:

```
using System.Linq;

....

List<List<string>> stringList = result.Select(
    lst => lst.Select(o => (o ?? "").ToString()).ToList()
).ToList()
```

Of course you could just read the DB value as a string in the first place...

```
public List<List<string>> ExecuteScalarEx()
{
    if (_conn.Trace)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Executing Query: " + this);
    }

    List<List<string>> stringList = new List<List<string>>();

    var stmt = Prepare();

    while (SQLite3.Step(stmt) == SQLite3.Result.Row)
    {
        int columnCount = SQLite3.ColumnCount(stmt);

        List<string> row = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            var colType = SQLite3.ColumnType(stmt, i);
            string val = (ReadColEx(stmt, i, colType) ?? "").ToString();
            row.Add(val);
        }
        stringList.Add(row);
    }

    return stringList;
}
```

Comment: I love this solution! But one question, why did you use  )?? "") ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because I don't know if `ReadColEx` could return `null` or not, e.g. if the value in the database is null. If you don't give a default value using the [?? null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), then you will end up doing `null.ToString()` and get a [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx). There are other ways around it if you want to keep things as null in `stringList`

Answer (score 3):

I assume that [`List.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is available, isn't it?

```
List<List<string>> stringList = result.ConvertAll(
    list => list.ConvertAll(obj => (obj ?? "").ToString()));
```

In this case(you've provided your code now) you should start with a `List<List<string>>` in the first place.

Comment: Nice I didn't know about that one. I was doing an answer with  `.Select().ToList()`

Comment: I don't have ConvertAll function! Thanks!

Comment: @MerlíPérezEscarpenter: why? MSDN states that it is supported in Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: I don't no but my visual doesn't detect this function... :S